# How to find the cutting points of normal distributions (ordered data case) - R

Tags: r, time-series, cut, normal-distribution

Suppose we have 2 rnorm, **rnorm1 = rnorm(100,0,1)** and **rnorm2 = rnorm(100,1,1)** and then we define **input = c(rnorm1, rnorm2)**.

1. How can we find the cutting point(in this case is point 100) of these 2 distributions and **keep the data in input ordered** (not changing the order at all)?
2. Further more, if we have multiple normal distributions(say more than 3), how can we do the same thing but **not defining the number of distributions**?

This question really bother me, could anyone give a favor?

Comment: This might be more suitable for https://stats.stackexchange.com . It would also help if you could clarify what parts of the problem are known - do we know that one distribution has mean 0 and the other mean 1? Or are we just trying to find 2 different distributions in the data?

Comment: yes those 2 distributions are known. for the first distribution: random, 100 point, mean = 0, sd = 1. for the second distribution: random, 100 point, mean = 1, sd = 1.
btw I am very new in here and I don't know if I can post an identical question at stats.stackexchange.com or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the simplest case, where you have 2 distributions and know the means of each, you can find the cutpoint by calculating the (log) likelihood for each possible cutpoint:

```
x = rnorm(100, 0, 1)
y = rnorm(100, 1, 1)
combined = c(x, y)

log_lik = function(cutpoint) {
    part1 = combined[1:cutpoint]
    part2 = combined[(cutpoint + 1):length(combined)]
   sum(dnorm(part1, mean = 0, log = TRUE)) +
    sum(dnorm(part2, mean = 1, log = TRUE))
}

res = sapply(1:length(combined), log_lik)
plot(res)
which.max(res)
```

This is just an ad-hoc solution to the problem though, for more robust statistical procedures you probably want to look at something like a changepoint analysis.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know the method you mentioned at all, no wonder I can't figure it out. I will look at change point analysis. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

If the population means are unknown, you can use the `strucchange` package.

Example assuming a unique breakpoint:

```
library(strucchange)
set.seed(666)
y <- c(rnorm(100,0,1), rnorm(100,1,1))
bp <- breakpoints(y ~ 1, breaks = 1) # assume a unique breakpoint
bp$breakpoints
# 102
```

If there's no assumption on the number of breakpoints:

```
library(strucchange)
set.seed(666)
y <- c(rnorm(100,0,1), rnorm(100,1,1), rnorm(100,0,1))
bp <- breakpoints(y ~ 1, breaks = NULL) # unknown number of breakpoints
bp$breakpoints
# 102, 213
```

[`changepoint`](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v058i03/v58i03.pdf) is another package for the detection of breakpoints.

`strucchange` more generally allows to search breakpoints assuming a linear regression model on the segments (e.g. it can detect a change of the intercept/slope in the case of the simple linear regression).

Comment: Thank you so much for this man! I am wondering what s the meaning of y ~ 1? So these 2 package can do the same thing by using different algorithms I guess?

Comment: `y ~ 1` is called a formula in R. In this context, it means that the model is `y[i] = constant + errors[i]`, where `errors` is a sample of the normal distribution with mean 0, and an unknown standard deviation. `changepoint` has more possible algorithms, but it accepts the model `y ~ 1` only, while `strucchange` accepts any linear regression model.

Comment: @AlexiHerc Do not hesitate to upvote the answers you find useful ;-) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Thank you again! I already did the upvote thing))) I have 1 more question for y ~1. What if I don't know anything about both mean and sd? The error parameter would still be sample of the normal distribution with mean 0, and an unknown sd?